# nth-of-type or nth-child work different on chrome?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, cross-browser

I have a problem building the template for a small project: tried both nth-child and nth of type but they seem to work different on Chrome, like it is indexed from 0... I have tried on other browsers and they all work the same. the code sample is:

```
.section:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background-color: rgb(69, 77, 96);
    color: #fff;
}
```

so I would expect to see that dark rgb color and white fonts on the first section, 3rd and so on.. on Opera and Mozilla (and inside eclipse preview) they look as expected. Though on Chrome the dark background it is applied only on even sections. Anyone had encountered this problem and has any hint?

[image: Outline of the HTML here]

the template uses also Bootstrap

Comment: Actually I cam back to my first version with nth-child(odd) and now it works cross browser. Curious thing since I have tried several times with that and did not behaved properly. I someone has a better idea of what could happen, if there's some hidden trick to this bug, I leave this question open for more ideas. The code that worked is exactly the same as in the code snippet, I just moved back to nth child:

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be due to the fact that nth-child and nth-of-type are normally intended to use on elements and not on complexer selectors (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type).

Try putting your even and odd items in a container element and then make your selector `div.item-container div:nth-of-type(odd)` for example, or `div.item-container :nth-child(odd)`.

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution worked, but still had the same problem on Chrome... I have solved the problem by using the nth-child again... don't know why... I mean I have tried it more than twice before trying the nth of type...

Comment: actually, now when editing something in that specific part of the front end, I noticed that I have applied your idea without noticing, and I think that this is the reason why now it works... though I am pretty sure I have tried that earlier, maybe it was also a caching problem, I've read other similar problems and sometimes the browser doesn't get all the modifications for some reason...

Comment: If you suspect that a web page isn't rendered according to your latest styling changes, you can always try CTRL+F5 in your browser. This way, you force the browser to fetch the *latest* versions of all files required for the web page to refresh.

Comment: Indeed, I made some research about what you've said, **CTRL + F5** should work better than plain F5 in order to be sure that I'm viewing the latest modifications and the page is not loaded from cache. I found also a detailed article about this: [link](http://podlipensky.com/2012/03/behind-refresh-button/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using bootstrap and happen to use their class and want to modify it, you have to make sure you select it the same way they did in their CSS

Comment: I was trying to access a section class, made sure it is accessed right and I have no other sections to interfere, yet it was not working.. after several tries, it worked normally and cross browser with nth child (though I have tried with it in the first instance)